# How to Convert this generic method from C# to VB.Net

Tags: c#, .net, c#-to-vb.net

I have the following code block in C#

```
private void Synchronize<T>(TextSelection selection, DependencyProperty property, Action<T> methodToCall)
{ 
    object value = selection. GetPropertyValue(property) ;
    if ( value != DependencyProperty. UnsetValue) methodToCall((T) value) ;
}
```

That I have converted to VB.

```
Private Sub Synchronize(Of T)(ByVal selection As TextSelection, ByVal [property] As DependencyProperty, ByVal methodToCall As Action(Of T))
    Dim value As Object = selection.GetPropertyValue([property])
    If value IsNot DependencyProperty.UnsetValue Then
        methodToCall(DirectCast(value, T))
    End If
End Sub
```

The calling method look like:

```
Synchronize(Of Double)(selection, TextBlock.FontSizeProperty, AddressOf SetFontSize)
Synchronize(Of FontWeight)(selection, TextBlock.FontSizeProperty, AddressOf SetFontWeight)
Synchronize(Of FontStyle)(selection, TextBlock.FontStyleProperty, AddressOf SetFontStyle)
Synchronize(Of FontFamily)(selection, TextBlock.FontFamilyProperty, AddressOf SetFontFamily)
Synchronize(Of TextDecorationCollection)(selection, TextBlock.TextDecorationsProperty, AddressOf SetTextDecoration)
```

My problem is with the DirectCast call; if my delegate argument can be a simple type (integer, double, etc) or an object.  DirectCast doesn't like the simple data types an InvalidCastException is thrown when I try to cast to a double.  Does anyone have a suggested solution to this problem?  I've also tried TryCast, but it doesn't like my (of T) and says it must be class contstrained.

Thanks all!

Ryan

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried removing the DirectCast and just passing in value?

Comment: @Tony - Didn't like that either.  Says specified cast in not valid.  I've added some code to give a little more context to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try CType() instead of DirectCast().

Comment: Tried it.  Bombs out as well.  I've tried the three type conversions I'm aware of (CType, TryCast and DirectCast) and none have worked for all cases.

Comment: I just tested with DirectCast and with CType.  The former raised an InvalidCastException.  The latter worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the errors you're seeing, it sounds like you may need to add a constraint on your T handle limit it to a class in order for the TryCast to be used.

I'm not really familiar with VB's TryCast method (or DirectCast, for that matter), but something like this might help [note that (Of T) -> (Of T as Class) ]:

```
Private Sub Synchronize(Of T as Class)(ByVal selection As TextSelection, ByVal [property] As DependencyProperty, ByVal methodToCall As Action(Of T)) 
    Dim value As Object = selection.GetPropertyValue([property]) 
    If value IsNot DependencyProperty.UnsetValue Then 
        methodToCall(TryCast(value, T)) 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Double and Integer will not satisfy the Class constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Use CType instead of TryCast/DirectCast. It should work like the casting in C# :

```
methodToCall(CType(value, T))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put multiple constraints on t

I believe the syntax is something like:

```
Private Sub Synchronize(Of T as {Class, Integer, Double})
```